# Who funded research before 1800?

Tags: funding, academic-history

The [Von Humboldt model of a university](http://www.jhuapl.edu/techdigest/views/pdfs/V06_N3_1985/V6_N3_1985_Muller.pdf) came about in the early 1800's. Von Humboldt's thought that the fundamental purpose of the university was to promote scientific inquiry and to unify teaching and research. This idea implies, of course, that the purpose of a university is to **create new knowledge**

However, a [previous SE question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68870/how-was-funding-handled-in-the-medieval-university) touches upon the idea that the initial goal of a university was not to discover new knowledge (as was Humboldt's view) but to transmit older knowledge.

With these ideas as context, where exactly were scientific advancements pursued prior to the Von Humboldt model?

Comment: Strange. I thought the _Academia_ of Plato and (less) the _Semicircle_ or Pythagoras were among the first places to promote scientific teachings and inquiry.

Comment: Maybe to be more fair, as you can see other discussing in the previous SE post, its not true that pursuing new knowledge wasn't a part of the function of a university, but it certainly wasn't the central theme.

Comment: I quote from wiki: _In at least Plato's time, the school did not have any particular doctrine to teach; rather, Plato (and probably other associates of his) posed problems to be studied and solved by the others._

Comment: That's fair. So is it your assertion that academia has always be the center for scientific advancement?

Comment: I simply provide info that already since 5th century B.C. there were places in Greece where the advancement of scientific knowledge was _the main_ goal. I am not sure that we can say that this was _always_ the case though.

Comment: And I used the word _strange_ because I thought that this idea of Humboldt you describe is at least 2500 years old.

Comment: The question in the title subtly deviates from the question in the main text. Which one do you want answered?

Comment: I'm really in search for context regarding the evolution of scientific research funding, and unpinning of the relationship between industry and academia. My implication is that research funding and scientific advancements are inseparably linked, so I'm unsure of the deviation youre referring to. But, I'd prefer direct context for Humboldts thinking.

Comment: The Lucasian Chair of Mathematics was founded in 1663. Even its earliest holders seem to have valued generating new knowledge, not just communicating old knowledge. Consider endowed chairs as a source of research funding.

Comment: To me "where" refers to an institution at which one is employed, "who funded" refers to a person or institution that paid for the research. A not uncommon model where the two differed was a man that married a rich women who funded her husbands research.

Answer (score 8):

In general, there was no central source of funding for research until recently.

If you were engaged in scientific research before modern times, you usually fell into one of a few categories:

- You had an official position, such as Royal Astronomer in the UK and other countries, that provided you with a salary in exchange for doing research.
- You had your own independent source of wealth that allowed you to survive.
- You worked another job, and "dabbled" in research in your "spare time."
- You were part of the church (e.g., Gregor Mendel) and did your studies and experiments in your free time.

Industry played at most a small role in funding research, directly or indirectly.

Comment: When you say, "official position," you mean government funded, or what entity? Did industry have no role in research, or was all research conducted in industry?

Comment: Governments did not "fund research": you were appointed by the ruler, and your position was paid for directly by the state. Industry did not pay for research, as there really weren't "industries" back then.

Comment: There were royal/government funded think tanks such as the Library of Alexandria and the Baghdad House of Wisdom.

Comment: I disagree that industry didn't fund research. Just to put a couple of examples, by 1800 industry had developed the steam engine and the automatic machine loom. Those innovations are due mostly to craftsmen and engineers who researched solutions to the practical problems they faced.

Comment: @Pere: While there were isolated developments, industry basically did not do "research." Thomas Savery was a military officer, and James Watt made his living as an instrument maker. The applications were industrial, but they were not "funded by industry."

Comment: @aeismail Maybe we don't understand the same by "research" and "industry". It's true that industry found "isolated developments", but the amount of isolated developments before and during the industrial revolution is impressive, and I would qualify it as research. However, if we understand "research" as organised research as we see today in academy, industry and scientifical societies, I must agree that that didn't exist in industry by 1800.